# Принципы ООП в С#

Tags: c#, ооп

В чем вообще его смысл? Чем код написанный , скажем так , в стиле ООП отличается, от обычного? И как вообще понять когда, как и какие классы использовать и для чего стоит создавать отдельный метод или функцию, а для чего нет? Как быстро можно научиться использовать принципы ООП, если уже есть начальный знания в этой сфере, но отсутствует понимание самого составления кода с применением ООП? Ну или посоветуйте какую-нибудь хорошую книгу. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте книгу Роберта Мартина "Чистая архитектура", в ней  в главе 3 приведён обзор  всех трёх парадигм программирования (структурное - то, что вы называете "обычным"), обьектно-ориентированного и функционального.

В двух словах:

- структурное ограничение накладывает ограничение на go to, что даёт возможность разбивать сложные программы на отдельные модули.
- объектно-ориентированное накладывает ограничение на косвеную передачу управления, что даёт возможность по использованию полиморфизма (переопределять поведение функции)
- функциональное программирование накладывает ограничение на присваивание и даёт возможность использовать чистые функции

Очень рекомендую прочитать полностью эти главы, а не останавливаться на таком сжатом пересказе.

Оставшиеся части вопроса слишком общие, не по формату stackoverflow.

Comment: Я бы не зарекался, что парадигм `"всего 3"`. Как минимум, не упомянута декларативная (:

Comment: OFF, вот этот Ваш ответ - для меня повод проголосовать за Вас на выборах модераторов :). Я бы еще пошел против "струи" и плюсанул сам вопрос.

Comment: Я увидел слово [парадигма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Парадигма_программирования) - там справа списочек... А если посмотреть на английском: [Programming paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) - список еще больше...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  Под рукой сейчас нет оригинала, но вот переводе использован именно термин "парадигма" а не "подход" или что-то другое, так что тут вопросы к автору книги. От себя могу добавить, что классификация - неблагодарная вещь, в зависимости от выбранного способа насчитать очень по-разному.

Comment: Да, я и хотел сказать, что при желании можно этих парадигм/подходов насчитать несколько десятков. И может автор вопроса по ссылкам найдет для себя что-то полезное.